# Openning command line Interface (CLI) in Zimbra Administration Console

Tags: zimbra

I am given an assignment to do some tasks in ZCS, but There is no instructions for where to enter commands in Zimbra Administration Console! Should I use PuTTy??? If yes, what is the address that I should type in host name?

I will appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on windows then Putty may be an option, simply put the hostname of your zimbra server. For example, if you zimbra server is hosted on mail.example.net, you should use that as a hostname. More preferably, you should use its IP address.